# Python: Plotting average Weekdays in succession for different Seasons

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I have a `DateTimeSeries Dataframe` with 15 Minutes values. Index is a `DatetimeIndex`. First Column holds the Values, 2nd the Day of the Week, 3rd the season. (I have custom defined seasons)

I would like to plot all the Season with their average hourly value per weekday in succession, Monday to Sunday. Something like this:

[image: Plot Goal]

I have managed to create 4 subplots, where each subplot represents one season, and all days of the week are depicted as an individual line. However, I can’t figure out how to plot one day after the other.

Here is what I got:
[image: My Plot]

This is my code, but I created some random numbers, so the plot results don't make much sense. But I don’t want to bother anyone with my csv files:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import numpy as np

#Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()

df["date"] = pd.date_range(start='2018', end='2019', freq = "15Min")
df=df.set_index(["date"])

df['Day'] = df.index.weekday

dw_mapping={0: 'Mon', 1: 'Tue', 2: 'Wed', 3: 'Thu', 4: 'Fri', 5: 'Sat', 6: 'Sun'} 
df['Day']=df.index.weekday.map(dw_mapping)

df['season'] = df.index.month
season_mapping={1: 'Winter',     #Winter
            2: 'Winter',         #Winter
            3: 'eS/lF',    #EarlySpring / LateFall
            4: 'eS/lF',    #EarlySpring / LateFall
            5: 'lS/eF',       #LateSpring / EarlyFall
            6: 'Summer',  #Summer
            7: 'Summer',  #Summer
            8: 'Summer',  #Summer
            9: 'lS/eF',       #LateSpring / EarlyFall 
            10:'eS/lF', 
            11:'eS/lF',     #EarlySpring / LateFall
            12:'Winter'}          #Winter
df['season']=df.index.month.map(season_mapping)

df["B1W"] = 1
df['B1W'] = np.where(df['season'] == 'Winter', df['B1W'] * np.random.randint(30, 60, df.shape[0]), df["B1W"])
df['B1W'] = np.where(df['season'] == 'eS/lF', df['B1W'] *  np.random.randint(20, 50, df.shape[0]), df["B1W"])
df['B1W'] = np.where(df['season'] == 'lS/eF', df['B1W'] *  np.random.randint(10, 30, df.shape[0]), df["B1W"])
df['B1W'] = np.where(df['season'] == 'Summer', df['B1W'] * np.random.randint(0, 10, df.shape[0]), df["B1W"])

#### Create Plot #### 
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 100
plt.style.use('ggplot')

ymin, ymax = 0, 50

fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2)
plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.2, hspace=0.3)
fig.suptitle("Building 1", fontsize=16)

fig.set_figheight(10)
fig.set_figwidth(15)

season = "Summer"
df.loc[df["season"]==season].groupby([df.loc[df["season"]==season].index.hour, 'Day'])["B1W"].mean().unstack().plot(
        ax=axes[0,0], ylim=(ymin,ymax), title = season, legend=False)

season = "eS/lF" #early Spring / late Fall
df.loc[df["season"]==season].groupby([df.loc[df["season"]==season].index.hour, 'Day'])["B1W"].mean().unstack().plot(
        ax=axes[0,1], ylim=(ymin,ymax), title = season, legend=False)

season = "lS/eF" #late Spring / early Fall
df.loc[df["season"]==season].groupby([df.loc[df["season"]==season].index.hour, 'Day'])["B1W"].mean().unstack().plot(
        ax=axes[1,0], ylim=(ymin,ymax), title = season, legend=False)

season = "Winter"
df.loc[df["season"]==season].groupby([df.loc[df["season"]==season].index.hour, 'Day'])["B1W"].mean().unstack().plot(
        ax=axes[1,1], ylim=(ymin,ymax), title = season, legend=False)

for ax in axes.flat:
    ax.set(xlabel='Time', ylabel='Power in MW')
    
for n in range(0,2):
    axes[n, 0].set_xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20])
    axes[n, 1].set_xticks([0,4,8,12,16,20])
    
# LEGEND
handles, labels = plt.gca().get_legend_handles_labels() # reorder Legend Labels
order = [1,5,6,4,0,2,3]      # specify order in Legend
axes[1,1].legend([handles[i] for i in order], [labels[i] for i in order], loc=1, ncol=7, 
                 bbox_to_anchor=(0.638,-0.2), frameon=True) # print and order LEGEND
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the `df` from yours.

```
df2 = df.reset_index()
df3 = df2.groupby([df2['date'].dt.dayofweek, df2['Day'], df2['date'].dt.hour, df2['season']]).mean().unstack()
df3.index.set_names(['dayofweek','weekday_abr','hour'], inplace=True)
df3
```

[image]
Set `dayofweek` as an index for sorting, since `weekday_abr` is an unordered categorical index. After `dayofweek` index rearranged the proper order of `Mon`,`Tue`, etc. We can drop it.

```
df3.reset_index().drop(columns=['dayofweek']).set_index(['weekday_abr','hour']).plot(figsize=(10,5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your input!
Unfortunately, this does not quite give me the results I am looking for: First of it creates only one value per day, though I want the course power curve for each day depicted (at least 24 vlaues per day). Secondly, I am looking for one plot (not 4 subplots) with only 4 lines in it, one for each season, covering Monday to Sunday (as depicted in my OP). 
I’d be grateful if you’d have any more input for me.

Comment: Ah, I get it, I misunderstood your demand. The structure would be avg. value per time (weekday followed by hour continuously), and hue by season.

Comment: This is exactely what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are attempting to produce a chart similar to the following.

[image: Weekly Seasonal Chart]

If so, following is a snippet of code with a simplified data set with one week of temperatures for each season.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

day     = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
winter  = [32, 41, 22, 15, 28, 36, 37]
earlyspring  = [46, 48, 40, 50, 52, 39, 55]
summer  = [68, 77, 66, 72, 80, 75, 88]
earlyfall    = [70, 55, 66, 69, 71, 58, 54]

plt.plot(day, winter,  label = "Winter")
plt.plot(day, earlyspring,  label = "Early Spring - Late Autumn")
plt.plot(day, summer,   label = "Summer")
plt.plot(day, earlyfall, label = "Early Autumn - Late Spring")
plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

Perhaps you could build upon that as a simple start.  Each seasonal list would be filled with the data from your "CSV" file.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you for your input NoDakker, much appreciated! 
Yes, the plot you presented is similar to what I am trying to achieve. 
However, I am not sure how to build up on your code using my df (15Min values for up to 3+years). I am looking to create at least 24 values per day (to depict the power curve of each day) and season. E.g. there should be four vales for each hour for every day of the week (one for each season). These values represent the mean of that very time (hour & day of the week) for each season.  
I’d be grateful if you have any more input for me.